# ora-06553 pls-306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ogc_x'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I´m trying a query in oracle 10g. It goes like this:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  h2h_reg reg,
  h2h_cat_estatus est
WHERE
  reg.FECH_APLICACION = SYSDATE
AND REG.ID_EST        = EST.ID_ESTATUS
AND est.tipo_estatus  = "X";
```

So it runs smootly, but when I try it adding a group by:

```sql
SELECT
  reg.id_arch,
  reg.id_prod
FROM
  h2h_reg reg,
  h2h_cat_estatus est
WHERE
  reg.FECH_APLICACION = SYSDATE
AND reg.id_est        = est.id_estatus
AND EST.TIPO_ESTATUS  = "X"
GROUP BY
  reg.id_arch,
  reg.id_prod;
```

I get the next message:

> ora-06553 pls-306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ogc_x'

Does anyone knows what´s wrong in my query?

Comment: You need `DISTINCT` since you're not using any aggregates.

Comment: How is it that the error you've posted references a function (`ogc_x`) that doesn't appear anywhere in your query?  Are you sure that the query you posted and the error that you posted go together?  Is one of the objects in the `FROM` clause a view that references the `ogc_x` function?  Also, strings in Oracle are enclosed in single quotes not double quotes.  If you used `= "X"` in Oracle, that would generate a syntax error.  It would be a different syntax error from the one you posted, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you've used double quotes on `"X"`.

this should be `'X'`.

the X object is an function in the MDSYS schema, "ogc_x", so when you say `est.tipo_estatus = "X"` instead of the correct `est.tipo_estatus = 'X'` it gets translated (as "" is as an identifier so "X" is the same as just typing X) to `est.tipo_estatus = mdsys.ogc_x` and of course fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT reg.id_arch, reg.id_prod
  FROM h2h_reg reg, h2h_cat_estatus est
 WHERE reg.FECH_APLICACION = SYSDATE
   AND reg.id_est = est.id_estatus
   AND est.tipo_estatus = 'X'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that this error was generated because I had used Oracle reserved words to name some of my columns, e.g. date, time, comment, etc.  Once I renamed the columns the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occured when the column does not exist