# Issue with dynamic execute immediate query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, execute-immediate

I have a code in my procedure that looks like this. But when i execute this code, i get the error as mentioned below.

The Error report that i got is:

**Error report -
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_Y'
ORA-06512: at line 20
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:

*Action:**

The error has something to do with  `primary_flag = "Y"` <-- this. How else can i write primary_flag = 'Y' inside a string?
The dynamic query is required in my case.

**MY CODE IS:**

```
    DECLARE

    p_assignee_id NUMBER := 10153;

    time_stamp timestamp := '12-DEC-2011';

    create_task_view_sql VARCHAR2(4000);

    BEGIN

       create_task_view_sql:=
                                         'select unique cp.sub_last_name 
                                          from cs_sr_contact_points_v cp 
                                          where cp.incident_id = 55500 
                                          and cp.contact_phone is not null 
                                          and primary_flag = "Y"';

       dbms_output.put_line(create_task_view_sql);

       execute immediate create_task_view_sql;


END;
```

Comment: Do you really need dynamic sql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ora-06553 pls-306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ogc\_x'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687766/ora-06553-pls-306-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-ogc-x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To embed quoted string in a quoted string, use two **single** quotes:

```
'...and primary_flag=''Y''';
```

Or you can use the newer `q'` syntax to avoid doubling up the embedded quotes:

```
q'[...and primary_flag='Y']';
```