# ORA-06553: PLS-306 Max Count Across Multiple Days

Tags: sql, count, max

I have a query that can acquire event counts on a specific day using

```
select eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator, count (eventid_nbr) as count
from eventlog
where received_date >= to_date('2017-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and sentindicator = 'Y'
group by eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator
order by trunc(received_date, 'DD');
```

However, I require the maximum count across x days and modify my query as follows

```
select y.eventid_nbr, trunc(y.received_date, 'DD'), y.sentindicator, max(y.count)
from (select count(eventid_nbr) as count from eventlog) y
where y.received_date between to_date('2017-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2017-07-03','YYYY-MM-DD') and y.sentindicator = 'Y'
group by y.eventid_nbr , trunc(y.received_date, 'DD'), y.sentindicator
order by trunc(y.received_date, 'DD');
```

Execution results in

> ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_Y'

Why am I receiving this issue?  Stack  has a similar issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687766/ora-06553-pls-306-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-ogc-x) but I am not using double quotes.

Comment: Your new query has y containing only one column, `count`, so you can't reference `y.received_date` or any of the other `y` columns.

Comment: @NetMage I removed the column references and trying select x, (select max(count) from (select count(y) as count from t)) from t where .... The script is running but I feel as though I am in the dark here.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need the other column values in the `select` or will just the max of the count do? What do you want to have happen if more than one day has the same max count?

Comment: @NetMage I would like the other column values in the select in addition to the max(count(eventid_nbr)) but only require the eventid_nbr and max(count(eventid_nbr)).  If two days have same count that happens to be the maximum, they can be duplicated without loss of data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the Max(Count()) and then return all matching groups / days:

```
select eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator, count (eventid_nbr) as count
from eventlog
where y.received_date between to_date('2017-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2017-07-03','YYYY-MM-DD') and sentindicator = 'Y'
group by eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator
having count(eventid_nbr) = (select max(count)
                             from (select count(eventid_nbr) as count
                                   from eventlog
                                   where y.received_date between to_date('2017-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2017-07-03','YYYY-MM-DD') and sentindicator = 'Y'
                                   group by eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator) )
order by trunc(received_date, 'DD');
```